# How to get response from Post request to Rest API on Android

Tags: android, rest, post, request

I sent a post request from Android to a Rest API endpoint and I do not receive a response from the server.
I need to get a response like this:

> [{"field":"login","message":"Login \"loooogin\" has already been
>   taken."}]

I thought maybe I can read the response in STATUS or MSG:

> ```
> Log.i("STATUS", String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));
>                         Log.i("MSG" , conn.getResponseMessage());
> ```

But my attempts aren't yielding results. The code in Android:

```
public void createAccount(final String login, final String carNumber) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("url");
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
                    jsonParam.put("login", login);
                    jsonParam.put("carNumber", carNumber);
                    Log.i("JSON", jsonParam.toString());
                    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                    os.writeBytes(jsonParam.toString());
                    os.flush();
                    os.close();
                    Log.i("STATUS", String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));
                    Log.i("MSG" , conn.getResponseMessage());
                    conn.disconnect();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
```

Comment: Hi @k_bm, just as a suggestion I'd say it could be worth having a look at the `Retrofit` library as it's usually what most people use to do network requests on Android nowadays.

Comment: @FrancislainyCampos You are right! But not each junior may learn it fast and may be stuck with some problems and **Best Practices**.

Answer (score 0):

You may write something like this if you did connect `Gson`, if not, replace `JsonArray` with `JSONArray` and do `get()` call by imbibed `JSONArray`.

```
JsonArray array = new JsonArray(jsonParam.toString());
    array.forEach(item -> {
        Log.i("JSON", item.get("login").asString())
    }
);
```

Comment: I don't need only a json array. I also need to get a message was it successful or no. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: try `conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK` that is for succes. Also check [full list of constants](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection#summary)